# Vercel - Cron Processing, Code only Executed on Deployment

Tags: next.js, cron, vercel

I'm learning how to setup a cron on Vercel, we have some tasks running on Heroku today, and we want to see how they perform on this platform.

I can see in the Usage report that the cron is being fired, however, I can't really see the code being executed.

However, when we deploy a change, it seems to work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS6uG.png)

Image showing that the cron is fired as expected.

We can also see that it has returned data from the function, the time matches the last deployment time.

[https://dw-router.vercel.app/api/pricefeed](https://stackoverflow.com)

The code:

```
//import type { VercelRequest, VercelResponse } from '@vercel/node';
import type { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { PriceFeed } from '@/lib/wharfsession';

export const revalidate = 0;
// GET for App Router, handler for Page Router
export async function GET(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
        console.log('---START---');
/*
        const authHeader = req.headers.get['authorization'];
        if (authHeader !== 'Bearer ${process.env.CRON_SECRET}') {
            return res.json({ success: false });
        }; */
        if ( req.method === 'GET' ) {
            try {
                const result = await PriceFeed(); //session.transact({ action: transferAction });

                //return res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: result });
                return Response.json({ success: true, data: result, status: 201 });
            } catch(err) {
                //return res.status(400).json({ success: false, data: err });
                return Response.json({ success: false, data: err, status: 401 });
            };
        } else {
            return Request.arguments;
        };
}
```

The vercel.json:

```
{
    "rewrites": [
        {"source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/"}
    ],
    "crons": [
        {
            "path": "/api/pricefeed",
            "schedule": "*/5 * * * *"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I don't understand is how doe cron call GET ? and why doesn't Vercel support a generic handler when that's what they have in their example for a serverless API route ?

I'm sure I missed something, somewhere. All I want to do is to run the code as if it was running in a *nix cron or a Node.js

Tried different examples from Vercel and old examples from community members.

Expect the cron to run the Pricefeed() function without the need of having an interface deployed.
The Project is in Production.
I'm using the Pro plan.

package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vercel/node": "^3.0.17",
    "@wharfkit/antelope": "^1.0.7",
    "@wharfkit/session": "^1.2.7",
    "@wharfkit/signing-request": "^3.1.0",
    "@wharfkit/wallet-plugin-privatekey": "^1.1.0",
    "next": "^14.1.0",
    "next-server": "^9.0.5",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "vercel": "^33.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.11.16",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.55",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

TIA

/F

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the project from scratch and now everything is working fine.